# MvcContrib grid lowercase sorting querystrings

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

When you use MvcContrib grid sorting out-of-the-box, it automatically appends the querystrings Column and Direction to your URL. For instance:

```
www.mysite.com/listing?Column=Bedrooms&Direction=Ascending
```

Is there a way to lowercase the querystrings (Column and Direction) so that you get this:

```
www.mysite.com/listing?column=Bedrooms&direction=Ascending
```

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 with MvcContrib version 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately those values are hardcoded in the `MvcContrib.UI.Grid.HtmlTableGridRenderer<T>` class:

```
// MvcContrib.UI.Grid.HtmlTableGridRenderer<T>
private RouteValueDictionary CreateRouteValuesForSortOptions(GridSortOptions sortOptions, string prefix)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
    {
        return new RouteValueDictionary(sortOptions);
    }
    return new RouteValueDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {
            prefix + ".Column", 
            sortOptions.Column
        }, 
        {
            prefix + ".Direction", 
            sortOptions.Direction
        }
    });
}
```

The `CreateRouteValuesForSortOptions` private method is invoked by the `RenderHeaderText` virtual protected method. So if you want to have lowercase parameter names one possibility would be to write a custom `GridRenderer<T>`.

Another possibility is to write a custom Route to make urls lowercase. You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://goneale.com/2008/12/19/lowercase-route-urls-in-aspnet-mvc/) which illustrates how to make all urls in an application to be lowercase but you could tweak it to your needs.